# Why am I getting this error while using android studio.?

Tags: android

Why am i getting this error ? I created a tool bar. It is showing that the class requires api level of 21 and the current min is 19.
Please help me.

```java
package com.example.whatsapp;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toolbar;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Toolbar mToolbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.main_page_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("WhatsApp");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

go to your build.gradle(app) section of your IDE,
scoll to the line that says

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.myapplication"
    minSdkVersion 23
    targetSdkVersion 30
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
```

under the minSdkVersion part, put 19

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried importing `androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar` instead of `android.widget.Toolbar`? It's available in `androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0`.

The error you're getting is more of a symptom in this case, and not the underlying condition - if you want to have the `minSdkVersion` set to 19 then you'll just have to utilize more of the unbundled libraries so that you can make use of "the fancy stuff from the future", in this case the `Toolbar` view introduced in Android L.